# InappBrowser plugin is not working

Tags: android, cordova, inappbrowser

please help me , I installed inappbrowser plugin , but when i call

**cordova.InAppBrowser.open**

it doesn't work !

```js
var iabRef = null;

iabRef = cordova.InAppBrowser('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
  <title>Hello World</title>
</head>

<body>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please provide the behaviour you are are seeing. Is there any error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all please remove and reinstall the inappbrowser plugin using this command `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser --save`
Then paste this code in your document.ready function

```
var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');
        ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) { alert(event.url); });
```

if you have any query please comment below .

Comment: I'm working on ionic project and used this piece of code, but while doing ionic serve am getting error as follows;

Property 'InAppBrowser' does not exist on type '(pluginObj: any, methodName: string, config: CordovaOptions, args: IArguments | any[]) => any'.
[ng] 90     var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```js
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function(){
cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');
});
```

You have missed open method.You can check reference here [link](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser)

Comment: I added the open methode but it's still not  working

Comment: are you testing in  mobile?

Comment: Show me your javaScript code.And make sure you build the application before run.

Comment: `<script>   var iabRef = null;

iabRef = cordova.InAppBrowser('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');  </script>`

Comment: You are not using device ready.I edited the answer check this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to call open method of InAppBrowser. If you are getting an error try adding the error event listener.

```
//Global
var appBrowserRef;


appBrowserRef = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('https://www.google.com/', '_blank', 'location=yes');

appBrowserRef.addEventListener('loaderror', loadErrorCallBack);

function loadErrorCallBack(params) {

var scriptErrorMesssage =
   "alert('Sorry we cannot open that page. Message from the server is : "
   + params.message + "');"

appBrowserRef.executeScript({ code: scriptErrorMesssage }, executeScriptCallBack);

appBrowserRef.close();

appBrowserRef = undefined;

}
```